# Is it possible to chain row.item?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a table

[image: table]

I have the following script

```
$Result = Query "SELECT [databasename], [servertypeA] from table GROUP BY [databasename], [servertypeA]"

    $Servers = @()
    $DB = @()

    foreach($row in $Result)
    {   
        $i++
        $DB += $row.Item("databasename")
        $Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA") #here i want to also store for servertypeB (so that Server array would store server1,serverx,servery and in next iteration server2,serverx,servery)

        cmd /c "PS.bat $somescript.ps1 $($Servers[-1]) $($DB[-1])"
    }
```

Can I somehow also create an index in $Servers array for `serverTypeB` here

```
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA") + $row.Item("servertypeB")
```

concatenating that way results in the following:

```
server1serverx
server1servery
server2serverx
server2servery
```

it should create an index for each server instead

```
server1
serverx
servery
server2
serverx
servery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing here.

`$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA") + $row.Item("servertypeB")` is saying "concatenate `$row.Item("servertypeA")` and `$row.Item("servertypeB")`, and add the result to `$servers`." Which is exactly what you're seeing.

You want to add each column into the array, not concatenate two columns.

```
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA") 
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeB")
```

Comment: ohhh interesting! what about the $Results query? would i have to edit that to include servertypeb? because with Groupby, it selects server1 once, but im afraid it would select only serverx and avoid servery because its ditinctively selecting server1....unless it doesnt work that way?